# How to make message of UIAlertController copyable in swift2, iOS9?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, uialertcontroller

I've a simple question: How can I make the message of an UIAlertController be selectable and copyable by the user?

The controller is initiated like so:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello World", message: "Copy Me!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

and displayed like so:

```
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adam's correct that UIAlertController doesn't provide text selection functionality, so a traditional copy/paste solution isn't going to work. You could alternatively provide a button on your `UIAlertController` that copies a string to the pasteboard.

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "Copy Me!"
```

Comment: But that button would have to be a UIAlertAction, and so it would also _dismiss_ the alert controller. What if the OP doesn't want that?

Comment: Yeah, then it's not doable. I suppose you could chain the original alert controller back to itself so that copying the text presents the original controller again —  the truly "correct" answer is that it isn't doable with this API.

Comment: The "copy" button would be fairly useless to me, it's ok I'll just do without for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. `UIAlertController` has no such functionality. It was implemented with `UILabel` components, which don't support copying text. You are not allowed to subclass `UIAlertController` either. The only option is to implement your own controller instead.